# python - binary search complexity

Tags: python

we got question in class that asks us if binary search with this algorithm:

```
def binary_search(array, needle_element):
    mid = (len(array)) // 2
    if not len(array):
        return False
    if needle_element == array[mid]:
        return True
    **if** needle_element > array[mid]:
        return binary_search(array[mid + 1:],needle_element)
    **if** needle_element < array[mid]:
        return binary_search(array[:mid],needle_element)
```

compare to an algorithm with elif instead of the two lasts if. does it stay on same time complexity? meaning is it still log(n)?

Comment: the if conditions are exclusive. So it will take more time, but still log(n), yes.

Comment: I rollbacked your edit which destroyed the question

Comment: According to [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) array slicing isn't O(1) so I don't think this implementation is O(log(n))

Comment: @ikkuh yes, the slicing could be avoided

Comment: he is right about slicing though, which means i cross the log(n) asymptotic bound :(?

Comment: oh you mean that because i dont enter the if statement means i avoid the slicing time consuming?